# Can't start OpenCVFrameGrabber

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, javacv

I am importing the following:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
```

This works fine. However, when I initialize a new `OpenCVFrameGrabber` object and then try to run the `.start()` method, as such...

```
OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber =  new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
grabber.start();
```

I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:174)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:456)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:581)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:79)
    ... 2 more
```

What is wrong? I'm guessing it's something wrong with my setup of OpenCV/JavaCV.